# How to export a null field on BIGQUERY

Tags: google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

When I try to export a JSON object through BigQuery, when there is a field with a "null" value, it disappears from the results' download.

An example of downloaded query:

```
EXPORT DATA OPTIONS(
  uri='gs://analytics-export/_*',
  format='JSON',
  overwrite=true) AS


SELECT NULL AS field1
```

Actual result is: {}

**When the expected result is: {field1: null}**

How to force an export with the null value like I showed on the expected result?

Comment: Try ````SELECT 'null' as field1````

Answer (score 1):

For this OP you can use:

```
Select TO_JSON_STRING(NULL) as field1
Select 'null' as field1
```

On [Export DATA documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/other-statements) there is no reference to an option that includes null values on output so I think you can go to [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) report page and create one request for it. Also, there are similar observations on other projects and points that it will not be supported yet, see details [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowPythonSDK/issues/17).

There are many workarounds for this, let me show you 2 options, see below:

**Option 1**: Call directly from python using bigquery client library

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import json

client = bigquery.Client()

query = "select null as field1, null as field2"
query_job = client.query(query)

json_list = {}
for row in query_job:
    json_row = {'field1':row[0],'field2':row[1]}
    json_list.update(json_row)
    
with open('test.json','w+') as file:
    file.write(json.dumps(json_list))
```

**Option 2**: Use apache beam dataflow with python and BigQuery to produce the desirable output

```
import argparse
import re
import json

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io import BigQuerySource
from apache_beam.io import WriteToText
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import SetupOptions



def add_null_field(row, field):
  if field!='skip':
    row.update({field: row.get(field, None)})
  return row


def run(argv=None, save_main_session=True):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        '--output',
        dest='output',
        required=True,
        help='Output file to write results to.')
    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)

    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
    pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = save_main_session

    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:

        (p
        | beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(query='SELECT null as field1, null as field2'))
        | beam.Map(add_null_field, field='skip')
        | beam.Map(json.dumps)
        | beam.io.Write(beam.io.WriteToText(known_args.output, file_name_suffix='.json')))

if __name__ == '__main__': 
  run()
```

To run it:

```
python -m export --output gs://my_bucket_id/output/ \
                 --runner DataflowRunner \
                 --project my_project_id \
                 --region my_region \
                 --temp_location gs://my_bucket_id/tmp/

Note: Just replace my_project_id,my_bucket_id and my_region with the appropriate values. Look on your cloud storage bucket for output file.
```

Both options will produce you the output you are looking for:

```
{"field1": null, "field2": null}
```

Please let me know if it helps you and gives you the result you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks, I have changed the output schema and this problem is no longer happening. We are not using Appache Beam in our project, although it is a nice option though